# Notation in derivation theorem

Tags: notation

[image]

Can you explain what does $
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ means?

Comment: It is a partial derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) with respect to variable $x^i$.

Comment: What a bad (replace *bad* with curse word) notation for the coordinates.

Comment: this book is very confusing

Comment: @GitGud The notation $x^k$ for coordinates isn't that bad. For example, $x=\sum x^ke_k$ represents an element of $\mathbb R^n$, while $f=\sum f_ke^k$ represents a linear functional on $\mathbb R^n$. I saw that in other books, say, Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*.

Comment: @GitGud Another reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: @FrankScience Not surprisingly your references are mainly related to physics, which supports my claim.